# Printed HTML table don't apply margins in all pages

Tags: html, css, page-break, printing-web-page, page-break-inside

I have this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    table { 
        page-break-inside: auto;
        margin-top: 50mm;
        margin-bottom: 50mm;
    }
    tr    { page-break-inside: auto; page-break-after: auto }
    thead { display: table-header-group;}
    tfoot { display: table-footer-group;}

    #header { 
        position: fixed; 
        width: 100%; 
        top: 0; 
        left: 0; 
        right: 0;
    }
    #footer { 
        position: fixed; 
        width: 100%; 
        bottom: 0; 
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header"> 
        <p>Personalised header</p> 
    </div>
    <div id="footer"> 
        <p>Personalised footer</p> 
    </div> 

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>heading</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><td>notes</td></tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Mor than 500 similar tr-->
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

It's a big table.
The table have top and bottom margins, but only apply margin-top in the first printed page and margin-bottom in the last printed page:

[image: First printed page with padding-top]

[image: Middle printed pages without paddings]

How can a I resolve this problem? I want the fixed positions of the headers and footers of the page, but the table I want that margins applies in all printed pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the @page selector to add spacing around your page like this:

```
@page { margin: 50px }
```

Comment: Actually that works, but I had simplified the problem too much, and eliminated an important part.
I want a header and a footer on each printed page.
I have modified the statement of the problem.
Sorry. I vote you positive because your answer is correct.

Comment: @hlastras There is a great article to this http://www.jessicaschillinger.us/2017/blog/print-repeating-header-browser/

Comment: Thanks, it's not exactly what I was looking for, but I think I can adapt to it

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it the following way.

```
@media print {
   table {
       position: relative;
       top: 50px;
   }
}
```